# How do I find this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I kinda got stuck on this one...

How do I find
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\tan(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}$$

What's the technique for solving limits of 0/0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\tan (\ln x)}{\ln x}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\tan u}{u}$$
via the substitution $u=\ln x$. Then,
$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\tan u}{u}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin u}{u\cos u}=1$$
since 
$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin u}{u}=1$$
The general technique for solving limits $0/0$ is with the [De L'Hospital Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: See that when $x\to1$ then $\ln(x)\to 0$ and that $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\tan(t)}{t}=1$

Comment: $+1^+\quad $ Short and sweet hint! $\quad\ddot\smile\quad$

Answer (score 4):

Besides the above approaches, we can use Taylor series:

$$\tan\log x=\log x+\frac{\log^3x}{3}+\frac{2\log^5x}{15}+...\,\,,\,\text{for}\,|\log x|<\frac{\pi}{2}\Longrightarrow$$

$$\frac{\tan\log x}{\log x}=1+\frac{\log^2x}{3}+\mathcal O(\log^4x)\xrightarrow[x\to 1]{} 1$$

Comment: Nice, Nice approach. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\tan(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sec^2(\ln(x))/x}{1/x}=
\lim_{x\to 1}{\sec^2(\ln(x))}={\frac1{\cos^2(\ln(1))}}=1
$$